# cuda header files

Tags: cuda

I have a file named "KernelUtil.cu" as follows

```
     __device__ int add(int a, int b)
      {
         return a+b;
      }
```

I have my main program which is "main.cu". I need to call the "add" function from here. How can I do it?? The following doesnt work.

```
    #include "KernelUtil.cu"
     __global__ void test()
   {
      int c = add(10,10);
   } 
   int main()
      {
           test<<<1,1>>>();
      }
```

giving an error add is already defined in main.cu

Comment: Have you checked `add` truly isn't defined somewhere else included though cuda.h? As far as I can see what you are trying to do should work. Perhaps using an include guard for your KernelUtil.cu might help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that you have a rule that automatically compiles all `.cu` files, meaning `KernelUtil.cu` is effectively compiled twice, once on its own and once when included in `main.cu`, and therefore `add` is duplicated.

Try renaming `KernelUtil.cu` to `KernelUtil.h` (or `.cuh`).